# Converting threshold MNDVI from Google Earth Engine to Jupyter Python?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I want to convert the script threshold for MNDVI from Google Earth Engine (JavaScript) to Jupyter (Python).

In this case, we make the threshold to 4 class MNDVI and the result is one layer, like this

```
mndvi_images = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    calculate_mndvi(year)
    for year in yearlist
])

print(mndvi_images.getInfo())


#CREATE VEGETATION CLASS

  threshold1 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(-1).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.2)).selfMask()
  threshold2 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.2).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.4)).selfMask().multiply(2)
  threshold3 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.4).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.6)).selfMask().multiply(3)
  threshold4 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.6).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(1)).selfMask().multiply(4)

  threshold1 = threshold1.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')
  threshold2 = threshold2.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')
  threshold3 = threshold3.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')
  threshold4 = threshold4.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')

# STACKING LAYER
stacking_layer = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([threshold1, threshold2, threshold3, threshold4])
print(stacking_layer,'staking'+i)
# Mosaic the ImageCollection.
stacking = stacking_layer.mosaic()
Map.addLayer(stacking, {'palette': ['e81410',  'f0fc0a',  '30bf21', '198f0d'], 'min':1, 'max':4},'Vegetation'+i)
```

But, when I run in jupyter python, there's an error like this:

> Input In [6]
> threshold1 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(-1).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.2)).selfMask()
> ^
> IndentationError: unexpected indent

How can I fix it?

---

When I run it's still error like this

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 120>()
    115 print(mndvi_images.getInfo())
    118 # CREATE VEGETATION CLASS
--> 120 threshold1 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(-1).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.2)).selfMask()
    121 threshold2 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.2).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.4)).selfMask().multiply(2)
    122 threshold3 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.4).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.6)).selfMask().multiply(3)

AttributeError: 'ImageCollection' object has no attribute 'gt'
```

Comment: [Indentation is significant for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=indentation#first-steps-towards-programming).  If you un-indent the `thresholdX = ...` lines, does the program function as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Transforming code from JavaScript to Python is quite straight forward when it comes to earthengine API.

The few things you need to take care of are the following:

- Python is not using ";" and "{" to split commands but indentation. so if your js code is badly indented you need to correct it.
- `and` and `or` are protected so you need to replace them by `And` and `Or`.
- Some anonymous can be tricky to translate into lambda function in Python you'll be better creating a named function in some cases.

For you specific code the issue is the 1st one and this is correct Python code

```py
mndvi_images = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    calculate_mndvi(year) for year in yearlist
])

print(mndvi_images.getInfo())


# CREATE VEGETATION CLASS

threshold1 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(-1).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.2)).selfMask()
threshold2 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.2).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.4)).selfMask().multiply(2)
threshold3 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.4).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(0.6)).selfMask().multiply(3)
threshold4 = mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').gt(0.6).And(mndvi_images.select('MNDVI').lt(1)).selfMask().multiply(4)

threshold1 = threshold1.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')
threshold2 = threshold2.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')
threshold3 = threshold3.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')
threshold4 = threshold4.toShort().select(0).rename('MNDVI')

# STACKING LAYER

stacking_layer = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([threshold1, threshold2, threshold3, threshold4])
print(stacking_layer,'staking'+i)

# Mosaic the ImageCollection.
stacking = stacking_layer.mosaic()
Map.addLayer(stacking, {'palette': ['e81410',  'f0fc0a',  '30bf21', '198f0d'], 'min':1, 'max':4},'Vegetation'+i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
###import relevant scripts
import os
from geemap.conversion import*
import geemap
import ee
####folder containing your *.js scripts
js_dir='/home/userxxxxx/gee_repos/Owner/tutorial_scripts/' 
## run the following lines to convert your *.js scripts to *.py scripts
js_to_python_dir(in_dir=js_dir, out_dir=js_dir, use_qgis=True)
print('Python Scripts saved at: {}'.format(js_dir))
```